# can I use document.prototype.getElementById to get an element in another element, not in the whole document

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I recently found on this javascript tip :

```
element_number = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(element_1, element_2);
```

It allows developers to use the indexOf method on an object wich is not an Array.

I would like to know if it is possible to use a similar syntax to call the getElementById method but not on the whole document (document.getElementById), just on an element like this :

```
my_div_2 = document.prototype.getElementById.call(div_1, "id_of_my_div_2");
```

The idea is that my document contains tabs and elements having the same id can be present several  times in the document.

If it is not possible, did somebody write a function doing that :
Search in an element another element by id.

Comment: Why would you want that? Ids must be unique in a document

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense as only one element with a given id is possible in a document.

So the only right syntax would be

```
my_div_2 = document.getElementById("id_of_my_div_2");
```

Don't reuse an id in a document. You probably can achieve the desired result using classes instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can accomplish what you want using `querySelector` instead.

```
my_div_2 = div_1.querySelector("#id_of_my_div_2");
```

Not supported in IE6/7.

- *Docs:* [MDN `element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelector)

---

That said, duplicate IDs are invalid.

This technique is useful if the same script is used on different pages where the ID may or may not be in a particular container.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I didn't know ID should be unique ! Thank you as well for the querySelector method even if I have to review my code.

Answer (score 0):

No. The [`getElementById` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) *must* be applied on objects of type `Document`, otherwise it would throw a `WRONG_THIS_VALUE` exception. You could try it with

```
myDiv1 = document.getElementById("div1");
myDiv2 = document.getElementById.call(myDiv1, "div2"); // no ".prototype"!
```

Comment: Does that last line actually work anywhere? I would doubt it.

Comment: @thesystem: No, but it would do what the OP intended and throw the exception I described. The OPs original try would have lead to something like "cannot access property `getElementById` of `undefined` (`document.prototype`)"

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you meant. You're saying you can verify the error by trying that code. Got it.